# Cannot navigate to another page

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a button and a tapped event:

```
private void btnSetLocationName_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationModel.LocationName = locationName.Text;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(GroupsPage));
    }
```

I want to just navigate to another page.  Unfortunately, Frame.Navigate does not work.  I have also tried to make sure it runs in the GUI thread: 
            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () => Frame.Navigate(typeof(GroupsPage)));

However, it should do, as the click handler for the button runs in the GUI thread.

The following error occurs:
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Comment: Have you tried navigating to a simple blank page? Perhaps there is an exception thrown when trying to instantiate the GroupsPage? also, is the GroupsPage.xaml defined in the same assembly?

Comment: Are you using the RTM version of Windows 8?

Comment: Hi there, yep, GroupsPage is in the main assembly and also, I have tried creating a separate Blank Page (which not inherit from LayoutAwarePage) however, it gets passed InitializeComponent, but then it fails.  It is Windows 8 RTM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, after commenting out bits of code until it worked, it turns out I had an empty OnNavigatedTo override:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

If you uncomment base.OnNavigatedTo it now works.

I think what threw me was that the error occurred when navigating FROM a page with this empty override. Also, the cryptic error message didn't help much.